# What are the meanings of itextpdf pdfcontentbyte addtemplate's parameters

Tags: itext

I am using itextpdf to merge some pdfs to a single one.
What are the meanings of itextpdf pdfcontentbyte addtemplate's parameters,there is no docs to describe them.

Comment: What's in the Javadocs?

Comment: It's also explained in great detail in the iText 5 book: http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/overview-of-the-graphics-state-methods-part-2-itext-5/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public void addTemplate(PdfTemplate template,
    double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f)
```

The six values `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` are elements of a matrix that has three rows and three columns.

[image]

You can use this matrix to express a transformation in a two-dimentional system.

[image]

Carrying out this multiplication results in this:

```
x' = a * x + c * y + e
y' = b * x + d * y + f
```

The third column in the matrix is fixed: you're working in two dimensions, so you don't need to calculate a new z coordinate.

> When studying analytical geometry in high school, you've probably learned how to apply transformations to objects.
>   In PDF, we use a slightly different approach: instead of transforming objects, we transform the coordinate system.

The `e` and the `f` value can be used for a translation. The `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` value can be used for a rotation and/or scaling operation.

[image]

By default the Current Transformation Matrix (CTM) is:

[image]

With the `addTemplate()` method, you can add a Form XObject to a canvas and define a position using `e`, `f`, e.g:

```
canvas.addTemplate(template, 36, 36);
```

This will add `template` at coordinate x = 36; y = 36.

By introducing `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, you can also rotate and/or scale the `template`.

**Update:** as mentioned in the comments, you might want to use the overloaded methods that accept an `AffineTransform` parameter if you don't like the Algebra of the transformation matrix.

Comment: You might want to advise the OP to use an overload with an `AffineTransform` parameter in case he is not comfortable with plain matrices.

Comment: Thank you for you guys.You really saved my day. I finally make scale and rotate working at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

the code below did the trick,thank for the guys who helped me.

```
        FileInputStream pdfInput = new FileInputStream(pdf);
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfInput);
        for (int index = 1; index <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); index++) {
            main.newPage();
            PdfImportedPage page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader,
                index);
            Rectangle pagesize = pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(index);
            float oWidth = pagesize.getWidth();
            float oHeight = pagesize.getHeight();
            float scale = getScale(oWidth, oHeight);
            float scaledWidth = oWidth * scale;
            float scaledHeight = oHeight * scale;
            int rotation = pagesize.getRotation();

            AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0);
            switch (rotation) {
                case 0:
                    cb.addTemplate(page, transform);
                    break;
                case 90:
                    AffineTransform rotate90 = new AffineTransform(0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, scaledHeight);
                    rotate90.concatenate(transform);
                    cb.addTemplate(page, rotate90);
                    break;
                case 180:
                    AffineTransform rotate180 = new AffineTransform(-1f, 0, 0, -1f, scaledWidth,
                        scaledHeight);
                    rotate180.concatenate(transform);
                    cb.addTemplate(page, rotate180);
                    break;
                case 270:
                    AffineTransform rotate270 = new AffineTransform(0, 1f, -1f, 0, scaledWidth, 0);
                    rotate270.concatenate(transform);
                    cb.addTemplate(page, rotate270);
                    break;
                default:
                    cb.addTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0);
            }
        }

private static float getScale(float width, float height) {
    float scaleX = PageSize.A4.getWidth() / width;
    float scaleY = PageSize.A4.getHeight() / height;
    return Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
}
```